# Drupal view nodes created by username specified in url

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I am trying to use views to make pages that will show posts by users according to their username in the url.

Basically, the following url should display all posts by someuser: http://drupalsite/posts/someuser

I have been trying for a few hours now but I can't find a solution. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Views you should be able to pass a URL argument of a username for the Node author to filter nodes.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out exactly how to do. I can set up the argument but it doesn't work. Do you have a link / screenshots to the exact settings I should use?

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/54455 explains arguments system, trying to find references for node author for a clean url.